# Closure in convex analysis

Tags: analysis, optimization

Why do sets $ri(C_1) \bigcap ri(C_2)$ and $C_1 \bigcap C_2 $ have the same closure. I'm reading Dimitri P. Bertsekas's *Convex Optimization Theory* and this question raises in reading the proof of **Proposition 1.3.8**. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

$ri C$ and $C$ have the same closure.

Let $x \in cl C$, and take $x' \in ri C$.  $ri C$ contains the open line $(x, x']$ making $x$ a limit point of points in $ri C$.  So $x \in cl( ri C).$  So $cl C \subset cl(ri C)$.

$cl (ri C) \subset cl C$ is true because $ri C \subset C$.

This can be used to proof the statement.